# ASP.NET MVC CKFinder image upload (add custom logic)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckfinder

I successfully installed CKFinder and it works great with default settings.
By the way i have my own logic to upload images to server (check size, resize, change quality, add watermark etc).
Can i combine CKFinder image upload process with my logic? What i want is CKFinder just grab image and pass it to my methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom plugin like is described [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Plugins/Writing_ASP.NET) and put your logic there.

> CKFinder functionality can be extended with server-side plugins. Although the full source code of the CKFinder server connector is available and can be modified in any way desired, a much better way of enhancing the CKFinder connector is to create a plugin.
>
> The main advantages of plugins are:
>
> - Upgrades are much easier.
> - The plugin code is stored in a single place.
> - Plugins can be easily disabled when they are not needed anymore.
>
> Common use cases:
>
> - Adding a new server-side command (i.e. fileditor and imageresize
>     plugin).
> - Working with uploaded files (i.e. watermark plugin).
> - Extending information returned by the Init command (i.e. imageresize
>     plugin).

Hope it helps you!